# docker not found when building in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I am trying to make sure my docker work or not in my Jenkins, 
I am running Jenkins in docker and it was running but when I check in Jenkins Pipeline, it said `docker: not found`

here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  jenkins:
    image: jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
    user: root
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker

  registry:
    image: registry
    container_name: registry
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

then I run `sudo docker-compose up -d` 
then the Jenkins is running, 
can I know why the docker not found ? is my docker-compose wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to bind `- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker`, as `- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` is engough to interact with host docker. you should not bind executable with docker container

remove this from the compose file and it should work.

```
- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```